# How to Add a default value in SQL server compact?

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-ce

I need to add default value column in SqlServer Compact....i am new to this SQL server compact so Plz anyone tell me the Solution of this....

Thanks In Advance

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You use the `DEFAULT` constraint when declaring the column.

See [this](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa175912%28SQL.80%29.aspx) MSDN article.

```
myCol INT NOT NULL DEFAULT (20)
```

In the example above, the values for column `myCol` will default to 20.

Comment: Thanks... Then how can i insert values in that mycol column

Comment: if i hav columns like name,id,mycol means how can i have to insert values in that table...

Answer (score 0):

https://technet.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/ms174123(v=sql.110).aspx

```
ALTER TABLE [tblename] ALTER COLUMN [columnname] SET DEFAULT <defaultvalue>
```